# Data Warehouse Fact Tables - MERGE OR DROP & INSERT

Tags: merge, data-warehouse, fact-table

I am building specific Fact Table for a Kimball-based EDW.

While loading fact table I came upon the realization on the different approaches.

Below the steps taken:

**The Source Data**

- Learner Absenteeism data.
- Learners are sometimes absent and these absenteeism's are capture again a learner.
- It can happen that the reason for absenteeism can change a few days later.
- It can also happen that the record is completely deleted a few days later.
- Source system has no form of Change Control features to indicate changed/deleted records.

**Sourcing Data**

- When sourcing the data only the current year's data is sourced.
- And no other data is kept in stage.

**Lookup Surrogates**

- Lookups are performed to replace natural keys with surrogate keys of the relating dimensions.

**Load Data in Fact Table**

- So now a clean conformed data set exist that need to to be loaded into the final Fact Table

Option One - Fresh Batch

```
DELETE FROM FactLearnerAbsenteeism WHERE SchoolYear = @CurrentYear

INSERT INTO FactLearnerAbsenteeism SELECT * FROM #Conform
```

Option Two - The Merge

```
MERGE dbo.FactLearnerAbsenteeism as DST

USING #Conform as SRC

*UPDATE CHANGES*

*INSERT NEW RECORDS*
```

**My concern is:** How I can i ensure records that no longer exist this year (deleted records) are removed. I prefer using the merge but using the DELETE option in MERGE can remove records from the previous years as they wont exist in the #Conform dataset.

Should I the rather source ALL data?
Should I keep the previous years data in STAGE and only source the current years data?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is sack whoever designed your source system! Just out of interest, I assume the source system has a database to store data: which database is it (oracle, SQL Server, etc)? For your immediate issue: (1) I wouldn't delete fact records, instead I would just flag them as deleted (i.e. a soft delete) (2) Only soft delete if the fact record date is within the last year and doesn't appear in your source/staging table

Comment: LOL @NickW ... yeah been trying to get these JAVA developers on board with proper Change Control features and implementing soft delete on their application SQL Database for years. But what does the SQL Dev know right :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose that you add a technical column "IsValid" in your fact table, set by default to 0. Then your loading process could be as follows :

**Step 1**
UPDATE FactLearnerAbsenteism SET IsValid = 0 WHERE SchoolYear = @CurrentYear

**Step 2**
Perform the Merge, and set Isvalid to 1 for each updated or inserted record.

**Step 3**
Decide what you want to do with the invalidated records : either you delete them in a last pass, or you keep them as it can represent an interesting piece of information enabling you to track the deletions in the source systems.

Disadvantage is that analysts need to be aware of this isValid parameter in their queries, to avoid overestimating the absentees, but I tend to prefer this as it captures the maximum information.